# Updated Bluez DBUS-API document?

Tags: bluetooth, glib, dbus, vala, gio

I just tried to run a vala bluez example (found in the [DbusClientSamples](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/DBusClientSamples) page) and I got this error:

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject:
Method "DiscoverDevices" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Adapter"
doesn't exist
```

Is the sample using deprecated API? If yes, where can I find an updated document about bluez's DBUS API? All documents I find (by googling) contain the `DiscoverDevices` method, so I'm quite confused.

Answer (score 11):

AFAICT org.bluez.Adapter is gone (I don't see it on my Fedora 20 system, running bluez-5.12).  In its place is [org.bluez.Adapter1](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt).  You can get all the latest documentation for the bluez D-Bus API at https://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

Comment: org.bluez.Adapter gone in favour of org.bluez.Adapter1? what a clusterfuck

Comment: Why? They needed to break backwards compatibility, so they added the new API with a new name.  That seems quite reasonable to me.  It would be great if everyone anticipated every use case and designed perfect APIs on the first try, but that seems unlikely…

Answer (score 5):

The best way to get the BlueZ DBus documentation is to download the source from the [BlueZ web site](http://www.bluez.org/), unpack it, then look in the `doc` directory.  All of the current DBus APIs are listed there.

I've been using those documents a lot lately.  You could ask for better, but they're good enough.  It is mostly obvious, and the most non-obvious issues are explained.

Answer (score 1):

The official [BlueZ](http://www.bluez.org/) site also provides a blog post for [BlueZ 5 API introduction and porting guide](https://www.bluez.org/bluez-5-api-introduction-and-porting-guide/), that provides some descriptions on their DBus APIs. At the top of the page they wrote:

> The BlueZ 5 D-Bus API contains significant changes compared to BlueZ
> 4. The bulk of the changes are due to the following features in BlueZ 5:
>
> - ...
> - Introduction of interface versions (e.g. `org.bluez.Adapter1`). When new versions are introduced we’ll try to keep supporting at least the two latest versions simultaneously.
> - ...

There is a section that discusses the DBus Object Manager:

> Instead, an application would discover the available adapters by performing a `ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects` call and look for any returned objects with an “`org.bluez.Adapter1`″ interface.

Also, aside from checking out the `docs` directory of the BlueZ source code (as mentioned in the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21154905/2745495) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38381620/2745495) answers), I find it also helpful to check the sample source codes in the `test` directory (https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test).

Here are parts of the [example-advertisement](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-advertisement) code:

```
BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME = 'org.bluez'
LE_ADVERTISING_MANAGER_IFACE = 'org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1'
DBUS_OM_IFACE = 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager'
DBUS_PROP_IFACE = 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties'

...

def main(timeout=0):
    ...
    adapter_props = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, adapter),
                                   "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties")

    adapter_props.Set("org.bluez.Adapter1", "Powered", dbus.Boolean(1))
```